# Multiple Threads in same transaction

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, threadpool, scheduler

I have multithreaded springboot application running on scheduler (set this property spring.task.scheduling.pool.size: 10). While running one transaction, we face slowness issue.

After checking debug logs, I could see "Thread-25" was handling transaction intially and as part of functional requirement, same thread inserts data in oracle database table.
Later, a new thread "Thread-33" picks up the transaction and performed required steps which caused more than 10 minutes of delay.

Attaching logs below for same.

{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:02:53.429+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Hydrated EntityKey (com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)): 123456789","threadID":"Thread-25","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}
{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:02:53.429+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Created new entity instance [com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)#123456789] : 350427865","threadID":"Thread-25","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}
{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:02:53.429+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Done materializing entityInstance : com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)#123456789","threadID":"Thread-25","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}

{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:15:29.086+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Hydrated EntityKey (com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)): 123456789","threadID":"Thread-33","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}
{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:15:29.086+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Created new entity instance [com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)#123456789] : 315651778","threadID":"Thread-33","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}
{"timestmp":"2023-10-16_10:15:29.086+0000","logLevel":"DEBUG","msg":"(EntityResultInitializer) Done materializing entityInstance : com.example.model.WorkUnit(123456789)#123456789","threadID":"Thread-33","sourceHost":"service-86dc79c694-pb4bf","logVersion":"1.5","category":"org.hibernate.orm.results.loading.entity"}

I am expecting to work it seamlessly

Comment: Change your expectations. Transactions cannot span multiple threads. Transaction and connection to the db are thread bound.